# How to use FreeImage.NET in a x64 targeting project (AnyCpu)?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, freeimage, target-platform

I'm trying to use the FreeImage .NET wrapper in my project, my ptoject targets AnyCPU and the dll wrapper will not work under this, it will only works if I target x86 machine.

When I try to load a file using the wrapper targeting AnyCPU or X64 it throws this exception:

```
"Se ha intentado cargar un programa con un formato incorrecto. (Excepción de HRESULT: 0x8007000B)" 

Translated:
"Intent to load a program with incorrect format (Excepción de HRESULT: 0x8007000B)"
```

I've tried to follow the steps to work with x64 freeimage in a net project: http://www.sambeauvois.be/blog/2010/05/freeimage-and-x64-projects-yes-you-can/

...But my VS2012 can't open any of the solutions, it says "can't find localized resources".

The source of freeimage and the wrapper is here: http://downloads.sourceforge.net/freeimage/FreeImage3154.zip

I need the dll converted to work with anycpu targeting, or a other solution to make it work, I'm working with VBNET.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to compile the freeimage library AND the .NET-wrapper to 64 bit.

http://www.sambeauvois.be/blog/2010/05/freeimage-and-x64-projects-yes-you-can/

Answer (score 4):

Simplest solution is to use [**FreeImageNET nuget package**](https://www.nuget.org/packages/FreeImageNET/). Caveat: I haven't tested this; I don't know how it deals with 32-bit vs 64-bit.

You can do so in your Solution Explorer - `"Manage NuGet packages for Solution..."`.

Below instructions are for those who wish to build the .NET wrapper themselves.

---

To clarify Bernhard's answer:

To use FreeImage in a 64-bit project, it isn't enough to compile the ".NET-wrapper" `FreeImageNet.dll` as 64-bit.
Must also make sure that you are using 64-bit version of `FreeImage.dll`, `FreeImage\Dist\x64\FreeImage.dll`.

Note that this is not an "Any CPU" solution. Set your main exe's project Platform to "x64".

To build `FreeImageNet.dll` in 64-bit (tested in `VS 2019 Community`):

- Download latest `"FreeImage DLL" [WIN32/WIN64]` archive from http://freeimage.sourceforge.net/download.html. You DON'T need the "Source distribution", unless you want to build the underlying C++ dll. As I write this, the file you download is `FreeImage3180Win32Win64.zip`.
- Open `FreeImage\Wrapper\FreeImage.NET\cs\FreeImage.NET.sln` in VS; let it convert project format to 2019.
- Unload `UnitTest project` (to avoid errors due to missing NUnit package).
- Set Build Configuration / Platform to `"x64"`.
- Open Library / Properties / Build - Set `"Treat warnings as errors"` to `"None"`. NOTE: This must be set for each `"Platform"` you build. So if you forgot to set Build Platform first, after setting Build Platform to x64, verify that this is still "None".
- Rt-click Library project / `Build`.
- Do for both `Debug` and `Release` build configurations, if you want to use Debug version with its `FreeImageNET.pdb` for symbols while debugging your app. You'll want the `Release` dll for the Release build of your app.
- Any .exe that references this Library, must also reference `FreeImage\Dist\x64\FreeImage.dll`.

Optionally, verify that you can build and run Sample 1 in that .sln:

- Set config to `Debug + x64`; startup project `Sample 1`.
- Build. If you run now, it won't find `FreeImage.dll`.
- Find what `bin` folder now contains `Sample01.exe`. That should also contain a copy of the `FreeImageNet.dll` you previously built.
- You need x64 version of the underlying C++ dll. Copy `FreeImage\Dist\x64\FreeImage.dll` into the folder where you found `Sample01.exe`.
- Set breakpoint at start of Sample's `Program / Main` method. Step through, look for any error messages in console window. Most importantly, make sure `FreeImage.IsAvailable()` check succeeds - doesn't say "FreeImage.dll seems to be missing".

Now you are ready to repeat this, with your own app:

- Set your main exe project's config to `Debug + x64`.
- Build. To make sure you know which bin folder you are building into.
- Copy `FreeImage.dll`, `FreeImageNET.dll`, and `FreeImageNET.pdb` into that folder that contains your `.exe`.
- [OPTIONAL] Add `FreeImage\Wrapper\FreeImage.NET\cs\Library\Library.csproj` to your solution. This is the "2019 format" version that VS 2019 created for you earlier. This makes it easy to debug into the wrapper sources.
- NOW reference the two dlls in your exe project, and debug your project as usual. (Or reference the `Library` project as a dependency, plus `FreeImage.dll`.)

NOTE: Copying those files directly into your bin folder is the "dirty" way to do this. Was easiest way to verify you can build and run with the dlls. Much better is to have those dlls be part of your "sources" under source code control, copied to the bin folder as part of your build process. Google elsewhere for instructions on that.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation... very useful.  Could you perhaps add a bit about the .NET version settings?  Sample 01 was set to .NET 2.0, and I think Library was set to 3.5.  Is it necessary to set these to the version your project uses, or can we set it to 4, or perhaps 4.5.1 and expect it to work with all 4.x.x versions?  (I remember having yellow warning icons in the Solution Explorer when I've had mismatched versions in the past... not sure if this is still a 'thing')  Thanks again for the detail, and FYI instructions work for VS2017 as well.

Comment: @AndrewMalcolm - I'm unsure about framework versions. I see that WinMerge guys are maintaining a freeimage fork in their [WinMerge github](https://github.com/WinMerge/freeimage) - take a look at what they do. They may be able to give you better advice if you have any problems.